# Channel Not Creating In A Category Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to create the channel in the category of the users liking but when i try to run the program it doesn't make the channel in the category i want it to.

Here's my code:

```
if sly.content.startswith("sly ctchan"):
x=sly.content.split("sly ctchan ",1)[1]
await sly.channel.send("Category Name")
y=await client.wait_for('message', timeout=15.0)
z=discord.utils.get(sly.guild.categories, name =y)
await sly.guild.create_text_channel(x, overwrites=None, category=z)
```

Comment: Can you specify how does the error look like?

Comment: there is no error... the channel gets created but not in any category

Comment: If you tried debugging by printing y and z, you would've found your problem: y is a Message object, not a string, therefore z would be None. use `name=y.content`  instead.

Comment: it shows z as none even with
`z=discord.utils.get(sly.guild.categories, name =y.content)`

Comment: i mean it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

Out of context, it's a bit difficult to see what how your code works. Are you using an `on_message` event for all your "commands"? Have a look in to [Commnads](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands#commands) they are pretty neat.

As Taku pointed out in the comment, `await client.wait_for('message')` returns a [Message Object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message). You know to use `.content` to get the message, but the second issue: All category names are displayed as uppercase, but casing can vary and the user will not know. We need to correct for this and make the check not care for casing.

Apart from that, you're have everything sorted out. I've added a check in there, so it will only accept message from the user who initiated the channel making. Otherwise anyone could write anything and it would start looking for a category. You can also add a final `if` statement, to only create the channel if it actually finds a category.

```py
    await sly.channel.send("Name of category:")

    # Check for the right user
    def check(m):
        return m.author == sly.author
        
    categoryName = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=15)

    categoryChannel = discord.utils.find(lambda cat : cat.name.upper() = categoryName.content.upper(), sly.guild.categories)

    # If it found a category
    if categoryChannel:
        await sly.guild.create_text_channel(channelName, category=categoryChannel)
        return

    # Didn't find a category? Tell the user it didn't find one, don't create a channel
    await sly.channel.send(f"Couldn't find a category by the name __**{categoryName}**__. Aborting")
```

Comment: did as you told and even added an else statement but not working. it doesn't create the channel and shows category doesn't exist. 
And after printing the value of categoryChannel it still shows as None. so i think that is the problem.

`@client.event 
async def on_message(sly):`

Comment: @DrGuileDish1 How far does the code run? Does it ask for `Name of category:`? If it does, then the code is executing just fine, and the issue lies in finding the category. I've tested this both as a command and `on_message` event, and i can't reproduce your issue. My bot finds the category without any problem. Try replacing `discord.utils.get` with `categoryChannel = discord.utils.find(lambda cat: cat.name == categoryName.content.upper(), sly.guild.categories)`

Comment: what happens is that when i run the code it asks for the category name and then shows couldn't find the category... just send me a msg at discord i'll send you a pic of what's happening
my discord id is: DrGuileDish1#5004

Comment: @DrGuileDish1 I've added you, It is a bit odd, I've tested this now with a couple of different bots, (even created a brand new one), over a couple of different servers. All work great.

Comment: @DrGuileDish1 I realised I had a mistake in the code. It's corrected now and should work just fine!